# How to find missing letters in an ascending sort

Tags: t-sql, missing-data

There is a table with the column PosNr/varchar(12). Some letters on position 12 are missing. The values are like

```
00
00.01
00.01.01
00.02
00.02.01
00.02.01.01
00.02.01.01a
00.02.01.01b
00.02.01.01d
00.02.01.01h
00.02.02
00.03
00.03.01
00.03.01.01
00.03.01.01a
00.03.01.01c
00.03.01.01d
00.04.02
00.04.03
00.04.03.01
00.04.03.02
```

It should find

```
00.02.01.01c
00.02.01.01e
00.02.01.01f
00.02.01.01g
00.03.01.01b
```

I create a temptable to insert the whole number and the letter itself with:

```
CREATE TABLE #Check (Pos varchar(12),Buchstabe char(1))

INSERT INTO #Check (Pos,Buchstabe)
SELECT
    PosNr
    ,RIGHT(PosNr,1) AS Buchstabe
FROM            dbo.tblAuftragGeräteDaten AS D
    INNER JOIN  dbo.tblLookupPosAZCheck AS L ON RIGHT(D.PosNr,1) = L.Buchstabe
WHERE (RIGHT(PosNr,1) LIKE '%[a-z]%');
```

Then I check which characters are missing. Therefore there is a table (tblLookupPosAZCheck) with just one column and all 26 characters from a-z stored in this column:

```
SELECT
    L.Buchstabe
FROM    dbo.tblLookupPosAZCheck AS L
WHERE   (L.Buchstabe NOT IN (SELECT Buchstabe FROM #Check))
    AND (L.Buchstabe <= (SELECT MAX(Buchstabe) FROM #Check))
```

Result:

```
Buchstabe
c
e
f
g
b
```

Now I get the missing characters. What I don´t get is the corresponding number (the first 11 characters):

```
00.02.01.01 (c)
00.02.01.01 (e)
00.02.01.01 (f)
00.02.01.01 (g)
00.03.01.01 (b)
```

I hope I could describe it well.

Comment: You are only returning 1 column in your select.  Try SELECT *

Comment: That´s why there are no more columns in this table.